# Netsuite Case statement

Tags: sql, case, netsuite

I want to use a case statement to return Direct To Consumer if the po/check field has a po that begins with `#WEB%`. Below is the formula text I am using.

```
CASE WHEN {otherrefnum} IS '#WEB%' THEN 'DIRECT TO CONSUMER' ELSE 0 END
```

I keep getting an error invalid expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `LIKE` instead of `IS`, and use brackets to escape `%` in your word.

**EDIT**

your `THEN` and `ELSE` result need to make sure the same type.

So let `ELSE '0'` instead of `ELSE 0`

```
CASE WHEN {otherrefnum} like '#WEB[%]%' THEN 'DIRECT TO CONSUMER' ELSE '0' END
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I appreciate your help.